# How to use react's reader in laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel

How Can I  use react's reader  https://github.com/gerhardsletten/react-reader   in laravel ? All tutorials in web about how to use react on frontend and laravel in backend as api meker . But I wanna frontend and backend to be in laravel but only wanna use this react reader . Is it posible ? How can I do it? also laravel  version is 5.2

Comment: You could have your laravel views contain a target container for the React component and render it into that. Do you need it to be react? You might be able to just use `epub.js` and include it into a laravel view just like any other JS dependency.

Comment: @CarlosReyes Is it possible to use laravel frontend and book load to be react . I mean Can I create api for only these books and rest leave as it is . And for only book load use api .

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the first paragraph of React-Reader's readme that it's just a wrapper around https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js.

You can use that like you'd use any other JavaScript library in your Laravel templates or whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You just have to include the react compiled script into your Laravel Blade Template and then render it with [ReactDOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html) like bellow:

**example.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

    <!-- ...your html -->

    <!-- This div will be used to render the react-reader component -->
    <div id="div-id"></div>
    <script src="{{ asset('your/compiled/component/route/your-component.js') }}"></script>

@endsection
```

**React component**

In the react component you must include ReactDOM to render the component inside the div. Import it at the top of your react component and at the bottom render the component in the div:

```
// Top of your file
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

//... Your react component

// Bottom of your file
ReactDOM.render(<Yourcomponentname/>, document.getElemenyById('div-id'));
```

Hope this can help you.